# my curve modifier does not modify my arrayed object around the curve?

Tags: modifiers

[image][image]my curve modifier does not modify my arrayed object around the curve?

Comment: That animated GIF is very annoying. Try uploading your blend file.

Answer (score -1):

The curve modifier has deformation axis options :

[image]

Try to click on X, Y or Z. Or check you did not clicked on the "eye" button on the top of the above picture.

Comment: I tried the curve modifier options but didn`t work for me. Another thing I have noticed is when i try to pick object my curve shapes name is not added instead its "BezierCircle" mine is named t circle and dont show up even when I write it in the text field

Comment: Could you share the blend file ?

Comment: You sure you selected the right curve in the Curve Modifier settings?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1376" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1376/)here is the file I have played around with the  options on the curve modifier but cant get the parts to align to follow the path of the curve

Comment: ok.. with your blend file modifying X, Y, Z works... but... you NEED to align the curve and the mesh with the axis or the result wont be predictable. In your file the curve is somewhere in 3d space.. but not aligned on a plane : that could be a wanted effect.. but for what you want to do.. surely not. Here is your file with two examples : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42145

Comment: If you look, you can see he showed he was trying to change the deform axes and nothing was happening.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood yes, but he showed this after an edit consecutive to the answer...